# Error while changing collation on an existing SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have an instance of Express 2014 running on my machine so I can examine customer DB's and run basic queries against them. Today I received one that uses some SP's for some of the queries and ran into this:

```
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between “SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS” and “Latin1_General_CI_AS” in the equal to operation
```

The obvious solution to these sorts of problems is to [change the collation of that database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms175835.aspx). However, that produced a long stream of these:

```
The object 'f_TenantFreeRentValue_GetAll' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then retry the operation.
```

I understand what is happening here, but come on... is there any lightweight solution to these sorts of problems? A script that runs on every object is not my definition of "light", is there a way to reset all of this on restore or something like that?